# You have missing dependencies! # Mandatory: spyder_kernels >=2.0.1,<2.1.0 : 2.0.1 (NOK)

Tags: python, spyder

I got that warning massage after upgrade to Spyder 5.0.0

> "You have missing dependencies!
>
> # Mandatory:
>
> spyder_kernels>=2.0.1,<2.1.0 : 2.0.1 (NOK)"

[image]

Answer (score 7):

the warning message may be misleading and unnecessary.  I checked, and I have spyder_kernels 2.0.1 installed.  The requirement is that the installed version needs to be greater than or equal to 2.01 and less than or equal to 2.1.0 — which mine is.

The issue is known and it will be fixed soon. Spyder isn't actually missing the dependency. It only thinks so. You can safely ignore the warning